# PHP + MySQL: How to select values from a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

The HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="1"/>This<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="3"/>That<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="4"/>Those<br/>
    <input id="btnClick" type="submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['foo'] as $va)
{
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("select sum(field) from table where field2 in ($va)");
    $stmt1->execute($data1);

    $result1 = $stmt1->fetchAll();
    print_r(var_dump($va));
    ...
 }
```

The problem:

This let me do the query only when I select one checkbox, if I select 2 or more, it just takes the last selected value.

What am I missing there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must change the name attibute to something else so you can access them independently such as name="fooThis" and name="fooThat" etc...

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson - That's not correct; in HTML, IDs must be unique, but names do not need to be.

Comment: sir you might want to visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293024/multiple-checkbox-not-checking-after-submitting/16293187#16293187

Comment: @ChrisForrence Names dont have to be unique, but they can be, so you can easily extract them in php/asp/etc responses. Sorry, for the misleading "You must".

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson - I mean, sure, names can be unique. And in a small case such as this, it may be handy. But when it gets to many checkboxes, it can get out of hand readability-wise ;)

Comment: @ChrisForrence Agreed but, that argument can go both ways, completely depends on the case in which they are being used, and the preference of the developer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to work: using `implode()` to build the array into a string.

```
$queries = implode( ',', $_POST['foo'] );

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("select sum(field) from table where field2 in ($queries)");
$stmt1->execute($data1);

$result1 = $stmt1->fetchAll();
print_r(var_dump($va));
```

If your inputs are not numerals:

```
$queries = implode( "','", $_POST['foo'] );

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("select sum(field) from table where field2 in ('$queries')");
$stmt1->execute($data1);

$result1 = $stmt1->fetchAll();
print_r(var_dump($va));
```

Comment: And how will you guard against SQL injection? ;)

Comment: OP's already using prepare(), assuming that class provides it. Chris does raise a good point though, make sure you are using prepared statements or otherwise escaping your inputs as you query the database.

Comment: PDO's prepare does guard against SQL injection...if you're using parameter markers (:boundvars or question marks). However, since the user input is both unescaped and unbound to the query, this particular query is unsafe.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yeah. `FIND_IN_SET()` in this case is definately better. ;)